# Facebook feed - page keeps reloading

Tags: facebook, feed

I am trying to post something on a facebook users feed and then afterwards redirect the user to another page, but it seems like the page just keeps reloading without any promt for sending user feed.

```
FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(1111111, null, null, null, null, null, redirectTo(), null, null);
function redirectTo()
{
     window.top.location = "/mywebsite";
}
```

If I just call the show feed with the id it works properly.

```
    FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(1111111, null, null, null, null, null, redirectTo(), null, null);
```

Anyone who knows why the first lines of code keeps reloading the page in an infinitive loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When registering the callback function, you want to pass the reference to the function and not actually call the function.  Remove the parentheses from redirectTo in your first line:

```
FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(1111111, null, null, null, null, null, redirectTo, null, null);
function redirectTo(){
     window.top.location = "/mywebsite";
}
```